# ¿Como puedo colocar una condición dentro de un estilo CSS Usando JS?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Lo que necesito es, que cuando ".top-nav-collapse" tenga el padding de 0 me coloque el ".menu .dropdown-menu" con el top del 100%

```css
@media(min-width:767px){
  .navbar{
    padding:20px 0;
    }
    
  .top-nav-collapse{
    padding:0;
    }
    
   .menu .dropdown-menu{
     top:100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola Julian, al menos que estés trabajando con Sass no es posible hacer un comparador lógico como if en css. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129699/can-you-use-if-else-conditions-in-css

en este caso tendrás que comprobar los diseños desde js

Comment: De momento CSS no permite hacer condiciones en base al valor de una instrucción. Para obtener el resultado que deseas es necesario usar javascript.

Comment: Como seria desde el js

Comment: Te he dejado la respuesta, por favor revisala y cualquier duda estoy pendiente de ello. No olvides calificarla si te sirve, mucha suerte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

como te dije antes

Hola Julian, al menos que estés trabajando con Sass no es posible hacer un comparador lógico como if en css. en este caso tendrás que comprobar los diseños desde js

Para hacerlo por js deberás obtener los estilos que tiene un elemento, te dejo un [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/op5qtxrd/) donde podrás obtener los estilos de un elemento Dom, mucha suerte.